# Download YouTube Videos from Mobile?

Tags: video, downloading, youtube, download-manager

Is it possible to download YouTube Videos on my New Samsung Galaxy Y android phone and have it stored in my SD card?

Comment: For the record this is against YouTube's TOS.

Comment: Apparently, it will be something soon (or already) available in India (http://www.livemint.com/Consumer/fMBN3yFAzQ7ok1sHj8JQTI/Google-to-make-YouTube-videos-available-offline-soon-in-Indi.html)

Comment: I dont have enough rep to answer. Most flexible way is to use youtube-dl through termux.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can take either of the following two approaches:

1. Use [tubemate](http://m.tubemate.net/). With this app you can browse YouTube and download the video just like you would download from websites like keepvid.com.
2. *The latest version of YouTube allows the videos that you opened or YouTube thinks you'll watch or have added to watch later queue to be downloaded in background so that you can watch it later. Read [here](http://mashable.com/2012/06/27/youtube-android-offline/).* -**> The preload option is no longer available in the official youtube app since version 5.6, see google support note [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4629400?hl=en)**

   > For the first time, YouTube will start downloading videos it thinks you might want to watch, whenever you’re plugged in and on Wi-fi.
   >
   > That’s great news for commuters, for example, who can now watch videos when outside their mobile coverage zone (or without paying for costly video downloads over 3G).
   >
   > YouTube, careful to draw a distinction between this and total downloading of its vids (which breaks its terms of service), is careful to point out that you’ll still need to be online for the first second when you press play.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use Tubemate. It has many options, one of which is the ability to  download the audio part alone so that you can also just listen to the video rather than watch it.

I later implemented a YouTube downloader script in my [browser app](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=126&info=Subhash_Browser_Feed_Reader_app). It has a flaw though - new videos loaded in the same page will not update the download link.

With the desktop browser disguise option and [a Greasemonkey script](https://vsubhash.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/download-any-youtube-anywhere-2016-user-js-for-opera-12-x-firefox-and-android/), it might be possible to make it work in a mobile device as well.

[image: Youtube downloads in Subhash Browser]

Comment: you implemented Greasemonkey support in mobile browser?

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020 and I use [NewPipe](https://newpipe.schabi.org) (it can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/releases) or [here](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/)). You can use it to download Youtube videos and to:

> Customize your download:
>
> - Set title
> - Choose between video or audio download
> - Download subtitles
> - Select the most suitable file format
> - Download the resolution you need

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the app.